# Приподнёс/преподнёс

Tags: орфография

Правильно я по-орфографичному это понимаю?

`Я преподнёс своей подруге мини букет одуванчиков.`

`Я к губам приподнёс брокколи, надкуснул и почувствовал блаженство.`

P. S. Я пишу без дефиса приставку *мини* в 1-м предл., только поскольку я её отношу не только к слову *букет*, а к словосочетанию *букет одуванчиков*.

Comment: Нет, не правильно, единственной случай возможно правильного использования у Лескова: "Николай Афанасьевич, войдя в комнату, вытянул свои ручки по швам, потом приподнес правую руку с картузом к сердцу, шаркнул ножкой об ножку..." то есть он поднес не к сердцу, напрямую, а приблизил к сердцу, до сердца, однако, не донося. В твоём варианте поднес к губам, так как ты тем более её надкусил, вряд ли зубы у тебя вперед губ могут быть. Все остальные случаи на нацкорпусе это ошибки ввиду 1.

Comment: Таким образом подходи только вариант с неполнотой действия, ввиду совершенного глагола поднести. В твоём 2 действие полное.