# Приподнёс к губам / преподнёс подарок

Tags: орфография

Правильно я по-орфографичному это понимаю?

`Я преподнёс своей подруге мини букет одуванчиков.`

`Я к губам приподнёс брокколи, надкуснул и почувствовал блаженство.`

P. S. Я пишу без дефиса приставку *мини-* в 1-м предл., только поскольку я её отношу не только к слову *букет*, а к словосочетанию *букет одуванчиков*.

Comment: Тоже дубляж твоего же вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475364/Приподнёс-преподнёс